# Printing Infopath form 2010(.xml) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: printing, infopath, document-library, publishing

My question is related to printing an Infopath 2010 form in Sharepoint 2010.I designed an Infopath 2010 form in Infopath Designer 2010 and published it to a form library in Sharepoint 2010.The end user fill the form and store it in .xml format in the document library.Now I would like to print the form filled by the end user? Any Ideas or suggestion about the above scenario?Please consider both browser based forms and normal forms

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider converting the InfoPath form to PDF as part of an automated workflow (or manual action) and send that to the browser for printing.

Have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html) that I wrote on the topic, it requires the use of a third party tool that I worked on as well.

Additional InfoPath based posts on this topic [can be found here](http://blog.muhimbi.com/search/label/InfoPath).